# Why does This SQL query give a syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, delphi, delphi-7

I have the following procedure which is executed on a button click (button1). After being prompted to log into the database, delphi throws the the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''AlphaMc'
>
> SELECT * FROM 'AlphaMc111'' at line 1'. Process Stopped. Use Step or Run to continue.

Here is the procedure:

```pascal
procedure TMainWin.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ADOConnection1.ConnectionString := 'Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};
  Server=db4free.net;Port=3306;Database=inventmanager;User=******;
  Password=******;Option=3;';

  ADOConnection1.Connected := True;
  ADOQuery1.Connection := ADOConnection1;

  ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM ''AlphaMc111''');
  ADOQuery1.Open;
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MySql [identifier](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html) quote character is the backtick, try

```
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM `AlphaMc111`');
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use quotes to escape column or table names. Use backticks

```
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM `AlphaMc111`');
```

Quotes are string delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

I think the Problem is the Query itself.

`AlphaMc111` does not need to be quoted as it is a Tablename

Quoted strings are only needed for Textinput in SQL Syntax.

try

```
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM AlphaMc111'));
```